# Cloudflare reverse proxy / proxy pass

Tags: reverse-proxy, proxypass, cloudflare

Hopefully a simple question.

Is it possible to use Cloudflare to proxy pass requests as you would in a normal reverse proxy webserver setup?

We have a subdomain that we'd like to rewrite all requests to another subdomain (not redirect).

We'd like requests to be rewritten as follows;

```
subdomain.example.com/login (IP 1.2.3.4) -> test-subdomain.example.com/login (IP 2.3.4.5)
```

With this in place the server at `2.3.4.5` `(test-subdomain.example.com/login)` will be serving files to requests coming from `subdomain.example.com/login`

Is this possible with Cloudflare?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way to do this would be for your default Origin server to do the ProxyPass. Everything still flows through Cloudflare if you do this.

You could also do this with Cloudflare Workers, but its not a feature of Cloudflare's general product offering.